# CSS/HTML: How to add a dropdown menu to existing navbar?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Hey guys can anyone help me I need this dropdown menu in my existing navbar. The dropdown menu should be on the right hand site of the navbar. please!

This is the html body part:

```
<body>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown, right">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

and this is my css code:

```
body {
    background-color: #D3D3D3; 
}

body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #000;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    background-color: #D2691E;
    color: white;
}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav,
    ul.topnav {position: unset}
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
```

Comment: First, `<li class="dropdown, right">` you need to remove that comma. Second, do you want to use CSS or a JS solution?

Comment: Try append using jquery `$(".topnav").append('<li>....</li>');`

Comment: @disinfor I want to use **CSS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the menu, then set it to `position: absolute` so that when it's displayed, it won't change the layout of the navbar. Then when you hover `.dropdown`, show the menu. Also changed the font color so the links are visible, removed `overflow: hidden;` from the navbar so that the menu can overflow outside of the menu and still be visible, and changed the `:hover` selector that changes the background color of the links to trigger on hover of the `li` instead of the `a` so that the dropdown link color stays changed as you interact with the dropdown menu.

```css
body {
    background-color: #D3D3D3; 
}

body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li:hover a:not(.active) {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    color: #000;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    background-color: #D2691E;
    color: white;
}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav,
    ul.topnav {position: unset}
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}

ul.topnav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
ul.topnav .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
}
ul.topnav .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to build a simple drop-down menu.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="dropdown">
  <input class="dropdown-toggle" type="text">
  <div class="dropdown-text">Account</div>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 132px;
}

.dropdown-text {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 10px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, .9) inset, 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 15px;
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.dropdown-text,
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1px;
  background: transparent;
  text-indent: -10px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  line-height: 32px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 140px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}


.dropdown-toggle:hover ~ .dropdown-text,
.dropdown-toggle:focus ~ .dropdown-text {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.dropdown-toggle:focus ~ .dropdown-text {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .2) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-toggle:focus ~ .dropdown-text:after {
  border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.dropdown-content:hover,
.dropdown-toggle:focus ~ .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility:visible;
  top: 42px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i guess you want something like this :

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: yes, but I need to put my css code with this css code together and I don't know how?!