# Align two elements under one another

Tags: html, css

So I want the list to be right underneath the `Button 3` without having the list nested instead the `Button 3`

Is something like this possible with `CSS`?

I've tried doing the `Left + absolute` and `margin-left` approach but it's not the best approached based on the page width changing. Is there a better way?

Side note: the solution must work in `IE9+`

Example of what i've got so far:

```css
.container{
width: 700px;
height: 40px;
background: black;
}

a.button{
   display: inline-block;
   color: #ffffff;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
}

.hoverButton ~ .dropdown{
  display: none;
}
.hoverButton:hover ~ .dropdown{
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
.hoverButton:hover ~ .dropdown .item{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a class="button">Button 1</a>
<a class="button">Button 2</a>
<a class="button hoverButton">Button 3</a>
<ol class="dropdown">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567364/css-html-how-to-add-a-dropdown-menu-to-existing-navbar

Comment: yes adjust some property (margin, left/top (with absoulte) translate etc etc)

Comment: could you wrap the button and then put the button and drop down in that wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: black;
}

a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.hoverButton~.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.hoverButton:hover~.dropdown {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
}

.hoverButton:hover~.dropdown .item {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="button">Button 1</a>
  <a class="button">Button 2</a>
  <a class="button hoverButton">Button 3</a>
  <ol class="dropdown">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you got a different solution which works in IE9+ ?

Comment: Nope...frankly, you shouldn't be using links there...especially without `href`. Why not use a proper parent menu in the first place?